# Strange white space when changing Wordpress to RTL

Tags: html, css, wordpress-theming

After I changed My wordpress site:http://mixamex.com to RTL a big white space appeared on the left side.
I tried to solve it using:

```
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  }
```

It worked on desktop but on mobile it made the problem even worse. I tried inspecting elements on the edge of the page and looking for strange margin or padding values but didn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

you should do this at the end of your css file or in main page, or if you can't access to main css file write them with !important :::

```
#td-mobile-nav{
display:none;
}

.td-menu-mob-open-menu#td-mobile-nav{
display:block
}

body{
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem. However it caused a minor problem in the featured image when browsing form mobile.

Comment: could you tell me what kind of problem do you have?

Comment: Post featured image is shifted to the left in mobile version
https://i.imgur.com/owRNt2O.jpg

Comment: I can't see that problem you posted its screenshot. does it solve?